# I can´t trigger a input type file with Ionic Framework in my device

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have maybe one week with this problem.

When I use a **input[type="file"]** field in my form, in **Ionic Lab** it works fine. In **Android emulator**, it works fine. But, when I run the app in my phone, and I click/tap in the field, nothing happens. The button is pressed, but the filepicker dialog doesn't show.

My input looks like it:

```
<input class="" id="image" type="file" name="image" ng-model="data.image" file="file"onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this.files)" style="display:none;" />
```

I tried something different, adding a button that trigger the click event in JS:

`<button type="button" class="button icon ion-filing" ng-click="openFileDialog()">Select</button>`

The method **openFileDialog()** does only this:

```
   $scope.openFileDialog = function() {
      alert('Test Open File DIalog');
      ionic.trigger('click', { target: document.getElementById('image')});
    };
```

The alert is shows when I click the button, but the event is not triggered. Again, it works fine in Ionic Lab and the Emulator, but not in my device. I tried and test this project too:

https://github.com/krystiangw/filepicker-ionic-example

But the result was the same.

**EDIT 1:**

It is so frustrating. I can´t make it works.

I tried making a simple blank project, with only:

```
  <ion-content>
          <input type="file" />
      </ion-content>
```

And nothing else. And again, in **Ionic Lab** and **Emulator**, opens the file choose dialog without problem, but when I run in my phone with:

```
ionic run android --device
```

Nothing happen. I don´t know if is my phone or some restriction.

**EDIT 2:**

After some investigation, I found this issue, without solution:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5294

My Android version is **4.4.2** But then, does this will never work in that Android version? Does someone knows If at least it has already been fixed in later versions? My Emulator has **Android 6**, and it works in that, as far as I could test.

Comment: Could it be an unrelated bug during load time on the device? Have you setup [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en) w/ web tools to make sure the app loads cleanly without errors?

Comment: I did not know about that tool, interesting. I checked it, and I don´t see any error in console, when the app opens, or when enter to the section of the form, or when I click the "select file" button. But you gave me a important tool from future tests, thanks! But for this error, I will continue looking for a solution.